# Strange output with tuple = (3**i for x in range(n))

Tags: python

I want to know what's happening with that part of the code. Why I have that output? Thank you in advance!

```
n = 10
powersOfThree = (3**x for x in range(n))
print(powersOfThree)
```

The output is: `<generator object <genexpr> at 0x055BEF90>`

Comment: what do you expect?

Answer (score 5):

Using parenthesis `( )` around your comprehension, that gives you a *generator* as introduced by Python here https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators

If you want a list, you can replace your parenthesis by `[` and `]`

```
>>> n = 10
>>> powersOfThree = [3**x for x in range(n)]

>>> powersOfThree
[1, 3, 9, 27, 81, 243, 729, 2187, 6561, 19683]
```

If you really wanted a tuple as output, then you can use `tuple()` :

```
>>> tuple(3**x for x in range(n))
(1, 3, 9, 27, 81, 243, 729, 2187, 6561, 19683)
```

Comment: This answer is good, but you should add that if the OP _does_ want a tuple for whatever reason, they should use `tuple(3**x for x in range(n))`

Comment: it's not a list comprehension it's a generator comprehension

Comment: Good point, although the OP is not really precise, maybe these parenthesis were the desire of tuples. Thanks. Editing

Comment: If I want to use a tuple I have to do: `powersOfThree = tuple(3**x for x in range(n))` that's because the immutable property, isn't it? Thanks for the answer!!!

Comment: @Josep It's because the "tuple operator" is really the comma `,`, not the parentheses. `..for..in..` is a *generator expression*, `(...,)` is a tuple literal. `tuple(..for..in..)` is the tuple constructor iterating the generator expression constructing a tuple.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you are trying to do. Your mistake was using '(' instead of '['.

```
n = 10
powersOfThree=[3**i for i in range(0,n)]
print(powersOfThree)
```